# Gson enum loose values by restart of application

Tags: java, android, gson

I am working on game that has some effects while playing

```
public enum Effect {
    DoublePoints(),
    IncreaseSwitch(),
    ShowOne(),
    ShowSame();

    @SerializedName("stored")
    int stored;
    @SerializedName("leftTime")
    int leftTime;

    Effect() {

    }

    public int getStored() {
        return stored;
    }

    public void setStored(int stored) {
        this.stored = stored;
    }

    public int getLeftTime() {
        return leftTime;
    }

    public void setLeftTime(int leftTime) {
        this.leftTime = leftTime;
    }
}
```

with `stored` i check the count of effects i have, and `leftTime` is time till end of effect.

to read and write effectively i use a `HashMap` to work with effects in runtime

```
private Map<String, EnumCollection.Effect> gameEffects = new HashMap<>();
```

and store it as `String` in DB.

Now i use Gson to parse the effects *from string* by initialization of game and *to string* by save.

```
// read
public void setEffects() {
    if (game.getEffects() == null) {
        gameEffects.put(EnumCollection.Effect.DoublePoints.toString(), EnumCollection.Effect.DoublePoints);

        EnumCollection.Effect switchEffect = EnumCollection.Effect.IncreaseSwitch;
        switchEffect.setLeftTime(3);
        gameEffects.put(EnumCollection.Effect.IncreaseSwitch.toString(), switchEffect);
        gameEffects.put(EnumCollection.Effect.ShowOne.toString(), EnumCollection.Effect.ShowOne);
        gameEffects.put(EnumCollection.Effect.ShowSame.toString(), EnumCollection.Effect.ShowSame);
    } else {
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, EnumCollection.Effect>>() {
        }.getType();
        gameEffects = new Gson().fromJson(game.getEffects(), collectionType);
    }
}

// write
private void saveGameValues() {
    String effectsString = new Gson().toJson(gameEffects);
    ...
}
```

Now.

I can success close and open application. Data writed and readed successfully in DB.

By repen of application i have *stored* and *leftTime* values, that i expect.

**BUT**

As soon i *restart* the application with `Android Studio` rerun button, *stored* and *leftTime* are 0.

When i log effects String i receive:

```
effects: {"ShowSame":"ShowSame","DoublePoints":"DoublePoints","ShowOne":"ShowOne","IncreaseSwitch":"IncreaseSwitch"}
```

With `@SerializedName` the values should be stored, or not?

What am i missing?

Is there are some problem with `TypeToken` ?

Comment: where is the database that saves your elements? External or inside Android?

Comment: @Boug, inside. is `Realm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going from `enum` to  `Object`

```
public class EffectItem {

    int stored;
    int leftTime;

    public int getStored() {
        return stored;
    }

    public void setStored(int stored) {
        this.stored = stored;
    }

    public int getLeftTime() {
        return leftTime;
    }

    public void setLeftTime(int leftTime) {
        this.leftTime = leftTime;
    }
}
```

from that

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, EffectItem>>() {
}.getType();
gameEffects = new Gson().fromJson(game.getEffects(), collectionType);
```

works as expected. And `HashMap`

```
private Map<String, EffectItem> gameEffects = new HashMap<>();
```

could still be used to better access to effects